# How to Read a YAML file in java?is there any package or jar defined for it?

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

I want to read a .YAML file and convert into java objects(POJO).It's a very big file and I can't write all the bean classes manually.Is there a way to create the bean classes automatically?

Comment: Your real question seems to be "how to generate POJO class from YAML" -- NOT what title claims. So you may want to change the title to reflect the real question (although that may have been asked before as well... I'd search for that).

Comment: my ultimate aim is to read a YAML file,but I believe i need to use java bean to map the YAML to java objects.since my Yaml file is huge i am not able to write the bean class manually.

Comment: the point is that the title should match your question and at this point it doesn't; or you are trying to ask too many and/or vague questions. At any rate question was closed as duplicate because of this; whereas if you asked the specific part of generating Java class you might have gotten an answer. There are Java libs that generate Java classes from sources like JSON Schema, and even sample JSON documents, so it is possible this is doable.